# Splitting up the Corinthians tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Unlike most books of the Bible, the two Corinthians epistles share a tag: [corinthians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corinthians). What do you think about splitting it up into [1-corinthians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-corinthians) and [2-corinthians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-corinthians)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for the most part, people are more concerned with 1 Corinthians than with 2 Corinthians. There are also only 18 questions with this tag and only two of them are about the second epistle [1](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/does-satan-still-masquerade-as-a-angel-of-light-among-christians) [2](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4382/what-is-the-significance-of-the-message-every-case-must-be-established-by-the-t). None of them appear to be about the church or the people of that area and time specifically.

So I don't think changing the tag serves a real or useful purpose today.

That said, I still think it should be done. If I were doing a study on 2 Cor. I don't want my search to include wading through all the 1 Cor. posts if it doesn't have to. Further, I may actually want to ask a question about the people and church of that time. The current tag excerpt excludes that use.

So, yes, they should be separated into:

- [1-corinthians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-corinthians)
- [2-corinthians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-corinthians)
- [corinthians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corinthians) where the excerpt says "the people and church of Corinth. Use [1-corinthians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-corinthians) and [2-corinthians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-corinthians) for the epistles."
- [church-in-corinth](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-in-corinth) Alternative option to the above tag. It's a little more descriptive, but it will show in all tag searches for "church", which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Presumably the same should also apply to 1- 2- and 3-John, which appear to be similarly absent.